# Google tag manager custom javascript variable increment

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to make a custom javascript variable that is incrementing a integer each time the tag is being fired, and the starting value should be 1.

since i have to write everything into one function i need to use window function in order to make the the integer variable global, any suggestions how that could look like?

```
function () {
     window.n=1;

     if (window.n <=1 ) {
     window.n++}
     return window.n;
}
```

Right now it is returning the value 2 every time the tag is being fired, how can i change this so it start increment from 1?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
function () {
  // increment window.n by one. window.n shall be undefined when
  // this function calls the first time so we use `|| 0` to have 
  // its value as 0
  window.n = (window.n || 0) + 1;
  return window.n;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25759928)